# Dealing with clock in Synopsys tetramax

Tags: vhdl, simulation, clock, hdl, vlsi

I am using tetramax to measure the fault coverage of some test-benches.
I am running the test-benches and dumping on a VCD file input and output of the core I want to test.

The clock as well as the reset are already managed by my external testbench.
I guess that therefore I do not need to add clock and reset in my Tetramax script.

I do not know however if specifying the clock has any side effect.... for instance in some internal delay computation between input and output.

Does anyone have more information about the effect of adding clock and reset in a tetramax script?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

> The clock as well as the reset are already managed by my external testbench. I guess that therefore I do not need to add clock and reset in my Tetramax script.

Wrong! You need to tell it which signal is the clock and which is the reset as these are special signals it needs to know about. It doesn't matter what your test-bench does. It shouldn't even be loaded.

Tetramax needs to know how to control the flip-flops in the design. Part of this is knowing how to reset them and clock them. When you specify the clock and reset it tells Tetramax how to do this. It needs to know this to generate or simulate test patterns. If you don't give it this information it can't do anything, or rather it's limited to testing things which don't involve flip-flops (which isn't much).

You'll also need to tell it about any test control signals that have to be enabled in order to enable test modes, scan chains, etc.

Comment: I am testing a processor... i did not insert any scan-chain because i would like to test the coverage of a piece of software. i am running the SW in modelsim. that's why i am managing the CLOCK externally. do you think i'll simply have to set the clock in accordance with the frequency i am using in modelsim?

Comment: Ah OK, I misunderstood. I saw TMax and thought ATPG, my mistake. So modelsim is dumping a VCD of pin values. You're then using the VCD to drive the pins of the processor in TMax? In that case I expect you'd have to identify the Clock and Reset signals to TMax, but not anything else. The VCD should take care of when they are driven. I'd need to be reaching for the documentation at this point to be sure though.

Comment: yes yes... i do not use Tmax to generate the tests... i want to use it only to simulate what is in the VCD. That's why I was assuming that i would not need to specify clock or reset. in the end to Tmax they should behave like any other signal. what do you think? ( i do not have experience in fault simulation)